# Changing colour of particular pcolor cell (not in the same colormap)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Sorry in advance if I have not worded the question properly.

I have two surfaces for which one represents terrain (and has an adapted form for the demcmap for its colormap) and the other represents a source point for a virus.

I want to plot the source point on top of the terrain as follows:

```
figure
pcolor(T)
colormap(cmap)
hold on
pcolor(F)
```

(where T is the terrain surface, cmap is my personally created colormap for terrain and F is the matrix containing all NaN's except for the one matrix entry which has a value ie the source point)

The problem I'm having is that I want the source point cell to be coloured red on top on the terrain surface, but I cannot seem to colour just this cell without changing the colormap of both of the surfaces.

Does anyone know how I could get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please upload sample data, for testing the solution?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101346-how-do-i-use-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the overloaded input option for `pcolor`

```
pcolor(X,Y,C)
```

For example, the following code creates an arbitrary grid and then overwrites the value of the first cell:

```
figure;
pcolor(magic(5));
hold on;
pcolor(1:2, 1:2, zeros(2));
```

If you have the indices of the origination point, `x,y`, and a value, `value`, you can write:

```
figure;
pcolor(T);
colormap(cmap);
hold on;
X = x:(x+1);
Y = y:(y+1);
pcolor(X, Y, value * ones(2));
```

Comment: That works but just gives me already what I had before unfortunately. For the surface: `pcolor(X,Y, value * ones(2));` I want the cell to be red, whereas everything else I still want to adhere to `colormap(cmap)`

Comment: So you want to use two different colormaps for the same plot?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The surface `F` only contains one entry which has a value, the rest are NaN's, so I was hoping I could just plot this surface on top of `T` and shade the one entry in red